# Generate OpenDocument Spreadsheets with PHP

Tags: php, excel, zip, ods

I'm trying to generate OpenDocument Streadsheets using PHP.
This is my code:

```
$content_xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><office:document-content ...';
$file = 'spreadsheet.ods'; // this one is beeing generated. It is not existent yet...
$zipfile = 'container.zip'; // this one already exists. It's in the same directory
// this script is in. I created the container.zip by unziping a usual .ods file,
// removing the content.xml and ziping again

$handle1 = fopen($zipfile, "r");
$handle2 = fopen($file, "w");

// writing the content of the `container.zip` to the `spreadsheet.ods`
fwrite($handle2, fread($handle1, filesize($zipfile)));
fclose($handle1);
fclose($handle2);

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($file, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);

// adding the xml string to the zip file
$zip->addFromString('content.xml',$content_xml);
$zip->close();

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
unlink($file);
```

If I open the generated file with OpenOffice - everything looks fine. But MS Excel for some reason is not able to open the file. I think the XML string in `$content_xml` is corrupt. I don't want to bother anybody with that string - it is huge! I got it from a simple ods spreadsheet. I just edited the `<office:body>...</office:body>` part.

I wondering whether this is a good way to generate spreadsheets. Does anybody know a tutorial for this task:

1. do all that zip stuff
2. structure of a simple content.xml in an ods file

Regarding "1. do all that zip stuff":
what I do here is generating the `content.xml` and adding it to the **root** of the .ods structure

```
Configurations2 // Folder
META-INF // Folder
Thumbnails // Folder
meta.xml
mimetype
settings.xml
styles.xml
```

By doing

```
$zip->addFromString('content.xml',$content_xml);
```

But how can I add a file NOT to the root of the structure but (let' say) to `Configurations2/images/Bitmamps`?

Answer (score 1):

You can find full details of the OpenOffice (OASIS) format on the [OASIS technical pages](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=office#technical) while The Open Office website provides [DTDs and some tutorials](http://www.openoffice.org/xml/general.html)